# How to have a measure lookup a value based on the row and column context?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

I need to Aggregate a number of multiplications which are based on the Row and Columns context. My best attempt at describing this is in pseudo-code.

```
For each cell in the Pivot table
    SUM
       Foreach ORU 
              Percent= Look up the multiplier for that ORU associated with the Column
              SUMofValue = Add all of the Values associated with that Column/Row combination
              Multiply Percent * SUMofValue
```

I tried a number of ways over the last few days and looked at loads of examples but am missing something.

Specifically, What won't work is:

```
 CALCULATE(SUM(ORUBUMGR[Percent]), ORUMAP)*CALCULATE(SUM(Charges[Value]), ORUMAP)
```

because you're doing a sum of all the Percentages instead of the sum of the Percentages which are only associated with MGR (i.e., the column context)

[Link to XLS](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=67E698690736D027!3352&authkey=!ABIytjZXV_mlEHQ&ithint=file%2Cxlsx)

[image: Picture of data and what I want the pivot to end up like]

[image: data model]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is by using nested SUMX. Add this measure to ORUBUMGR:

```
ValuexPercent :=
SUMX (
    ORUBUMGR,
    [PERCENT]
        * (
            SUMX (
                FILTER ( CHARGES, CHARGES[ORU] = ORUBUMGR[ORU] ),
                [Value]
            )
        )
)
```

For each row in ORUBUMGR you will multiply percent by ....
the sum of value for each row in Charges where ORUBUMGR ORU is the same as Charges ORU. Then you sum that product.